# Optimal number of partition for kafka topic on 5 brokers with replication factor=3 in 1 cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

What is optimal no. of partition for a topic that has 5 brokers and replication factor=3? 
Total there are only 6 topics in this cluster.

Machine configuration that each broker is running as follows.

```
Memory=16gb
Porcessor= Octacore, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz
```

Any challenges other than open file for 1000 partitions per topic??

Comment: This blog post should help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/

Comment: Thanks Mathias, this is helpful. 
As per the article, i should be good for 1500 partitions. 
 
"As a rule of thumb, if you care about latency, it’s probably a good idea to limit the number of partitions per broker to 100 x b x r, where b is the number of brokers in a Kafka cluster and r is the replication factor"

Answer (score 5):

Starting since Kafka 1.1.0 it's recommended to have up to 4'000 partitions per broker and up to 200'000 partitions per cluster.
Read more [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-supports-200k-partitions-per-cluster).

Pls, **note** that even if you can create a large number of partitions it doesn't mean that your hardware will be able to support it. Make sure you scale your cluster hardware(CPU, RAM, HDD etc) accordingly to your load.